# C - Getting a Debug Assertion Failed Error by reading a csv-file

Tags: c, readline, assertion, fgetc

i am just doing a program in C, which has to read different files in csv-format. Every file consists of two lines. 
The first line describes what topics are saved, while the second lines contains the data of the topics. Every file has 
6 columns. The data are information like dates, source and category. I actually wrote a program that get the path and
gives the content in one dynamical char array back, but there is always a Debug Assertion Error that crashes it all the time. My Code is:

```
char* readfile(char csvpath[]) {
FILE *csv;
int c;
int countcontent = 100;                 //counter for the length of the content array
int counter = 0;                    //counter  of the amount of the inserted chars
char *temp;                     //temp = buffer
char *content = (char*)calloc(100,sizeof(char));    //content of the file
csv = fopen(csvpath,"r");
while(c = fgetc(csv) != EOF) {              //while file isnt at the end
    if(countcontent <= counter) {
        realloc(content,100*sizeof(char));
        countcontent += 100;
    }
    temp = (char*)calloc(20,sizeof(char));
    fgets(temp,20,csv);
    content = concat(content,temp);         //concat is my own function and add the 2. string behind the 1.
    counter+= 20;
}
fclose(csv);
return content;}
```

[image: Assert Screenshot]
Actually i ignore that there are two different lines, cause i want to delete the first one at the end anyway, because no data is saved there. But can you help me to find the solution for this error?

Comment: First of all, [in C you should not cast the return of `malloc` (and family)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Secondly *use a debugger*.

Comment: Also note that `c = fgetc(csv) != EOF` is equivalent to `c = (fgetc(csv) != EOF)`

Comment: `stream != NULL` failing in `fgetc` sounds like your file wasn't opened.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line

```
realloc(content,100*sizeof(char));
```

The [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) function *returns* a pointer to the reallocated memory. Think about what would happen if the [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) call can't just resize the already allocated chunk, and has to actually allocate a completely new chunk of memory, because it can't automatically update the pointer you pass to it.

Another problem with that statement is that it doesn't matter how much more memory you need, you will *always* allocate `100` bytes. The size argument you provide to [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) is the *new* size.

Oh, and remember that [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) can fail, and return a `NULL` pointer. If you don't want to loose your original pointer, you need to have a temporary variable to store the returned pointer, and check it for `NULL`.

Comment: You mean i have to use content = realloc(content,100*sizeof(char));? Actually when i use debugger my program don´t come so far, it stops already in the while instruction.

Comment: @LAN Read my whole answer, and follow the links to the `realloc` reference and read that as well.

Comment: @LAN As for the crash in `fgetc` (most likely) it probably because the `fopen` call failed and gave you a `NULL` pointer. For ***all*** functions that return a value should ***always*** check the value returned for errors.